# How can I read a file to an InputStream then write it into an OutputStream in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, integration, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to use basic Java code in Scala to read from a file and write to an **OutputStream**, but when I use the usual **while( != -1 )** in Scala gives me a warning "comparing types of Unit and Int with != will always yield true".

The code is as follows:

```
    val file = this.cache.get(imageFileEntry).getValue().asInstanceOf[File]
    response.setContentType( "image/%s".format( imageDescription.getFormat() ) )

    val input = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( file ) )
    val output = response.getOutputStream()

    var read : Int = -1

    while ( ( read = input.read ) != -1 ) {
        output.write( read )
    }

    input.close()
    output.flush()
```

How am I supposed to write from an input stream to an output stream in Scala?

I'm mostly interested in a **Scala-like** solution.

Comment: Performance-wise, it might be a good idea to use an intermediate buffer instead of reading and writing one byte at a time.

Comment: That's why there is a `BufferedInputStream` there.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could do this:

```
Iterator 
.continually (input.read)
.takeWhile (-1 !=)
.foreach (output.write)
```

Comment: Ok, this looks like a real Scala solution, but is this **continually** call load the file into memory or is it going to call this function as the foreach loop runs? Also, can you elaborate a bit on this takeWhile method? Why didn't you have to use the _ parameter or define a parameter yourself?

Comment: @Maurício It's an iterator, so everything is done only on-demand. Until `foreach`, nothing really happens -- you just get new `Iterator` objects that do some pre-processing before `next` or `hasNext`. On `foreach`, an `output.write` is executed for each `input.read`, and then its value is promptly forgotten and garbage collected.

Comment: It would be nice to have a version using the scala-io incubator project

Comment: It should be noted that for the maximum performance, both input and output stream should have been buffered (using Buffered{Input,Output}Stream). It will still be significantly slower than the [non-Scala-like way](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.OutputStream%29)

Answer (score 19):

If this is slow:

```
Iterator 
.continually (input.read)
.takeWhile (-1 !=)
.foreach (output.write)
```

you can expand it:

```
val bytes = new Array[Byte](1024) //1024 bytes - Buffer size
Iterator
.continually (input.read(bytes))
.takeWhile (-1 !=)
.foreach (read=>output.write(bytes,0,read))
output.close()
```

Comment: This is assuming that you're ok just reading 1024 bytes though. What if I don't know how much I need to read until I reach something like a delineator?

Answer (score 7):

Assignment statements always return Unit in Scala, so `read = input.read` returns Unit, which never equals -1. You can do it like this:

```
while ({read = input.read; read != -1}) {
  output.write(read)
}
```

Comment: You can't have more than one statement in a while/if/for clause. This code yields a compilation error. But thanks for the assignment thing, i thought it would behave like java.

Comment: Hi Mauricio! Yes the {} are the key point in his example. Let's call them a block. Everything inside will be executed and the result is eventually returned having the type of the last expression.

Comment: sorry, added the braces a little late;)

Answer (score 5):

```
def stream(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream) =
{
  val buffer = new Array[Byte](16384)

  def doStream(total: Int = 0): Int = {
    val n = inputStream.read(buffer)
    if (n == -1)
      total
    else {
      outputStream.write(buffer, 0, n)
      doStream(total + n)
    }
  }

  doStream()
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution. The above solutions are horribly slow. One call per byte read of overhead? Really? How is that acceptable in a bulk data mover?

Answer (score 0):

We can copy an inputstream to an outputstream in a generic and type-safe manner using typeclasses. A typeclass is a concept. It's one approach to polymorphism. In particular, it's *parametric polymorphism* because the polymorphic behavior is encoded using parameters. In our case, our parameters will be generic types to Scala traits.

Let's make `Reader[I]` and `Writer[O]` traits, where `I` and `O` are input and output stream types, respectively.

```
trait Reader[I] {
  def read(input: I, buffer: Array[Byte]): Int
}

trait Writer[O] {
  def write(output: O, buffer: Array[Byte], startAt: Int, nBytesToWrite: Int): Unit
}
```

We can now make a generic copy method that can operate on things that subscribe to these interfaces.

```
object CopyStreams {

  type Bytes = Int

  def apply[I, O](input: I, output: O, chunkSize: Bytes = 1024)(implicit r: Reader[I], w: Writer[O]): Unit = {
    val buffer = Array.ofDim[Byte](chunkSize)
    var count = -1

    while ({count = r.read(input, buffer); count > 0})
      w.write(output, buffer, 0, count)
  }
}
```

Note the implicit `r` and `w` parameters here. Essentially, we're saying that `CopyStreams[I,O].apply` will work iff there are `Reader[I]` and a `Writer[O]` values in scope. This will make us able to call CopyStreams(input, output) seamlessly.

Importantly, however, note that this implementation is generic. It operates on types that are independent of actual stream implementations.

In my particular use case, I needed to copy S3 objects to local files. So I made the following implicit values.

```
object Reader {

  implicit val s3ObjectISReader = new Reader[S3ObjectInputStream] {
    @inline override def read(input: S3ObjectInputStream, buffer: Array[Byte]): Int =
      input.read(buffer)
  }
}


object Writer {

  implicit val fileOSWriter = new Writer[FileOutputStream] {
    @inline override def write(output: FileOutputStream,
                               buffer: Array[Byte],
                               startAt: Int,
                               nBytesToWrite: Int): Unit =
      output.write(buffer, startAt, nBytesToWrite)
  }
}
```

So now I can do the following:

```
val input:S3ObjectStream = ...
val output = new FileOutputStream(new File(...))
import Reader._
import Writer._
CopyStreams(input, output)
// close and such...
```

And if we ever need to copy different stream types, we only need to write a new `Reader` or `Writer` implicit value. We can use the `CopyStreams` code without changing it!